# Sliding Down A Small NSView Over An Existing NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm working with a NSWindow that displays various NSViews when buttons are pressed (a settings panel, essentially).
I'm trying to get a smaller NSView to slide out with a NSPopUpButton and some NSButtons from the top of the main NSView when a button is pressed.

What's a good starting point for figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Do you want a sheet?  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000002-BABFIBIA